# How to dynamically render thymeleaf tag which is coming from back-end

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

Is there any way to render thymeleaf tag which is coming from back-end?
For example I have json (`textObj`) shown below coming from back-end.

textObj.json

```
{ 
"title" : "Page Title",
"text" : "blah blah blah blah <div th:include=\"include::include\">my content</div>"
}
```

include.html

```
<div th:fragment="include">
My Actual content
</div>
```

page.html

```
<h2 th:utext="${textObj.title}"/>
<th:block th:utext="${textObj.text}" />
```

When I render the page it's directly showing thymeleaf tags in html source, is there any way we can process them before rendering on screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are returning your object to 'page.html'. If you are loading your view from spring, Add your java model to modelAndView:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page")
public ModelAndView loadPage() {
ModelAndView response = new ModelAndView();
    TextObj textObj = new TextObj();
    textObj.setTitle("Test title");
    textObj.setText("Some text <div th:include=\"include::include\">my content</div>");
    response.addObject("textObj", textObj);
    response.setViewName("page");
    return response;
}
```

And rendered like below:

```
<h2 th:utext="${textObj.title}">Sample Title</h2>
<p th:utext="${textObj.text}">Sample text</p>
```

Just worked fine for me.